# Kendo shared tool tip displays even if we dont hover over the bar

Tags: kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-chart

I am using a kendo chart. I have stacked columns in my chart. I am using shared tooltip. The problem is that by default even if i am not hovering over the series bars(hovering just above the bars) the tooltip shows up. I want the tooltip to be displayed only when my mouse is over the bar.Is there a way to change this default behaviour?

```
<div id="chart">
</div>
<script> 
$("#chart").kendoChart({ 
  seriesDefaults: { type: "column", stack: "true" }, 
  series: [{ data: [1,2,3] },{ data: [4,5,6] },{ data: [7,8,9] }], 
  tooltip: {
            visible: true, 
            shared: true 
           } 
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help you with this if you posted your code that initialized the tooltip.  Are you using a custom template for the tooltip?

Comment: Or even better, can you reproduce the issue in a Dojo?  http://dojo.telerik.com/

Comment: Please see the code snippet in Dojo. Here non of the bars are in the range 18 to 20 however, if you move your mouse in that range it still displays the tool tip. How can i configure this so that the tool tip is only displyed when we hover over the stacked bars. http://dojo.telerik.com/OBONU/3

Comment: the code to create the tool tip is as follows   <div id="chart"></div>  
  <script>
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    seriesDefaults: {
      type: "column",
      stack: "true"
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1,2,3]
    },{
      data: [4,5,6]
    },{
      data: [7,8,9]
    }],
    tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      shared: true
    }
  });
  </script>

Comment: When you add code, please add it to your original question instead of a comment.  Makes it a lot easier to read that way.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo requires JQuery, so you have to initialize the kendoChart inside a JQuery function.  What threw me off is the fact it was still working...just not with the desired functionality.  I'm surprised the chart didn't just stop working altogether.  Either way, If you update your code as below, you should see the tooltip working as expected.

```
<div id="chart">
</div>

<script>      
   $(function() {            
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            seriesDefaults: { type: "column", stack: "true" }, 
            series: [{ data: [1,2,3] },{ data: [4,5,6] },{ data: [7,8,9] }],           
            tooltip: {
                visible: true, 
                shared: true
            }
        });         
   });
</script>
```

I also created a Dojo showing the working example:  http://dojo.telerik.com/iboqU

Comment: In the example ,you have not marked the tool tip as shared. If you mark the tool tip as shared and then see the behaviour, you will observe that it displays the tooltip even if the mouse is not exactly over the bars. Even if its above the bar it displays the tool tip. I am not sure why this is happening. I suppose it is the default behaviour of shared tool tip.Can you suggest any work around for it so that the tool tip is displayed only when you hover over the bars??